# [WP 8.1]Error when validating the app to store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I had an windows Phone 8.1 Application upgraded from WP 8.1 SL, In silverlight and WP8.0 code iam using a Project RingToneEditor Class Library, It Consists Classes like ACMDriverDetails.cs, AcmInterop.cs, AcmMetrics.cs.. etc...

in the AcmInterop.cs i have code like as below

```
namespace OnlineVideos.RingToneEditor
{

    using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    internal class AcmInterop
    {
        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmDriverClose(IntPtr hAcmDriver, int closeFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmDriverDetails(IntPtr hAcmDriver, ref AcmDriverDetails driverDetails, int reserved);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmDriverEnum(AcmDriverEnumCallback fnCallback, IntPtr dwInstance, AcmDriverEnumFlags flags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmDriverOpen(out IntPtr pAcmDriver, IntPtr hAcmDriverId, int openFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmFormatEnum(IntPtr hAcmDriver, ref AcmFormatDetails formatDetails, AcmFormatEnumCallback callback, IntPtr instance, AcmFormatEnumFlags flags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll", EntryPoint="acmFormatSuggest")]
        public static extern MmResult acmFormatSuggest2(IntPtr hAcmDriver, IntPtr sourceFormatPointer, IntPtr destFormatPointer, int sizeDestFormat, AcmFormatSuggestFlags suggestFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmFormatTagEnum(IntPtr hAcmDriver, ref AcmFormatTagDetails formatTagDetails, AcmFormatTagEnumCallback callback, IntPtr instance, int reserved);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmMetrics(IntPtr hAcmObject, AcmMetrics metric, out int output);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamClose(IntPtr hAcmStream, int closeFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamConvert(IntPtr hAcmStream, [In, Out] AcmStreamHeaderStruct streamHeader, AcmStreamConvertFlags streamConvertFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll", EntryPoint="acmStreamOpen")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamOpen2(out IntPtr hAcmStream, IntPtr hAcmDriver, IntPtr sourceFormatPointer, IntPtr destFormatPointer, [In] WaveFilter waveFilter, IntPtr callback, IntPtr instance, AcmStreamOpenFlags openFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamPrepareHeader(IntPtr hAcmStream, [In, Out] AcmStreamHeaderStruct streamHeader, int prepareFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamReset(IntPtr hAcmStream, int resetFlags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamSize(IntPtr hAcmStream, int inputBufferSize, out int outputBufferSize, AcmStreamSizeFlags flags);

        [DllImport("Msacm32.dll")]
        public static extern MmResult acmStreamUnprepareHeader(IntPtr hAcmStream, [In, Out] AcmStreamHeaderStruct streamHeader, int flags);

        public delegate bool AcmDriverEnumCallback(IntPtr hAcmDriverId, IntPtr instance, AcmDriverDetailsSupportFlags flags);

        public delegate bool AcmFormatChooseHookProc(IntPtr windowHandle, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public delegate bool AcmFormatEnumCallback(IntPtr hAcmDriverId, ref AcmFormatDetails formatDetails, IntPtr dwInstance, AcmDriverDetailsSupportFlags flags);

        public delegate bool AcmFormatTagEnumCallback(IntPtr hAcmDriverId, ref AcmFormatTagDetails formatTagDetails, IntPtr dwInstance, AcmDriverDetailsSupportFlags flags);
}
```

The Complete code worked successfully with out errors, But i try to submit my app to Store it is Showing Error like below.

[image]

How to solve this error and update my app in the store.

IIf there is any replacement to this please suggest me.?

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: Looking at the error message it is obvious that the dll import from `Msacm32.dll` are not accepted for the app submission

Comment: Is there any alternative for that..

Comment: Not really depending on the format you want to handle, you might get lucky enough to get a pure mp3 handling lib, but I would think that handling wma in pure .net would be difficult